# Check if variable is callable

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I want to create a helper function `isCallback` that returns whether a function is callable.

I have a type that can either be `true` or a callback with a specific argument. In my current code, I have lots of checks like `typeof foo === 'function'` and I want to refactor those with the `isCallback` function.

I created this helper function `isCallback`:

```
export const isCallback = (maybeFunction: unknown): boolean =>
  typeof maybeFunction === 'function'
```

My problem is that when I use it TypeScript is confused:

```
if(isCallback(foo)) {
  foo(myArgs)  // Error here
}
```

and complains with:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'true | ((result: Result) => void)' are callable.
    Type 'true' has no call signatures.
```

How can I create a function that returns `true` if the variable is callable and TypeScript knows about it, too?

Comment: `(maybeFunction: unknown): boolean` -> `(maybeFunction: unknown): maybeFunction is Function` or whatever interface you want to use for the function. But point is that a type guard should use `is`.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know that `boolean` means "whether or not it's a function"? Are you looking for [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)?

Comment: Maybe following VLAZ suggestion, something like this would work, using type guards? `function isCallable(maybeFn: unknown): maybeFn is Function { return typeof maybeFn === 'function'; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) pointed out, using [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) works.

```
export const isCallback = (
  maybeFunction: true | ((...args: any[]) => void),
): maybeFunction is (...args: any[]) => void =>
  typeof maybeFunction === 'function'
```

Comment: To be more generally useful (and a better reflection of what the actual implementation checks), it should probably be `(maybeFunction: any) => maybeFunction is Function`. That would still narrow from `true | ((...args: any[]) => void)` to `(...args: any[]) => void`.

Answer (score 1):

a clear generic function,

```js
function isCallback<T>(maybeFunc: T | unknown): maybeFunc is T {
  return typeof maybeFunc === 'function';
}
```

you could use the type `Function` as a default value for `T`, for example `<T = Function>`. but I wouldn’t recommend it. if you're using `eslint`'s `@typescript-eslint/ban-types` rule, it's gonna complain about using the type `Function`.